# How to create a node in the center of a edge with bend

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I wish to draw a graph such that the red vertices are exactly in the center of each blue edge. The code is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pointblue/.style={fill=blue, circle, minimum width=3pt, scale=0.6}}
\tikzset{pointred/.style={fill=red, circle, minimum width=3pt, scale=0.6}}

% blues vertices
\coordinate (X) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate (Z) at (2,-1.5);
\coordinate (T) at (-0.5,2);
%% blues vertices.
\node at (X) [pointblue] (x) {};
\node at (Z) [pointblue] (z) {};
\node at (T) [pointblue] (t) {};

%%% blues edges
\draw[thick, blue] (z) edge[bend right=25] (x);
\draw[thick, blue] (z) edge[bend left=45] (x);

\draw[thick, blue] (x) -- (t);
\draw[thick, blue] (x) edge[bend left=60] (t);
\draw[thick, blue] (x) edge[bend right=60] (t);

% reds vertices
\coordinate (X2T2) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (X1T1) at ($(X)!.5!(T)$);
\coordinate (XT) at (0,1);

\coordinate (ZX) at (1,-0.5);
\coordinate (Z1X1) at (0.5,-1.3);

% reds vertices.
\node at (ZX) [pointred] (zx) {};
\node at (Z1X1) [pointred] (z1x1) {};

\node at (XT) [pointred] (xt) {};
\node at (X1T1) [pointred] (x1t1) {};
\node at (X2T2) [pointred] (x2t2) {};

% reds edges
\draw[thick, red] (x2t2) edge[bend right = 60] (z1x1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image: Figure]

I am calculating the coordinates of reds vertices manually (note that they are not well in the center). I know how to calculate the coordinate of the center for the edges without the bend (for example, in the code I use: `\coordinate (X1T1) at ($(X)!.5!(T)$);`). Is there any way to calculate the center of a blue edge with a bend without it being manually done?

Comment: It looks like you are using the `calc` library. Please always include a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define the coordinates of the node separately from the node. Just use

`\node[pointblue] at (-0.5,0) (x){};`

The red nodes can be defined using `midway` as part of the `\draw` statement. Also, `\draw` statements can be combined when they have the same style, and multiple styles can be defined in one `tikzset`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{pointblue/.style={fill=blue, circle, minimum width=3pt, scale=0.6},
    pointred/.style={fill=red, circle, minimum width=3pt, scale=0.6}}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% blues vertices
\node[pointblue] at (-0.5,0) (x){};
\node[pointblue] at (2,-1.5) (z){};
\node[pointblue] at (-0.5,2) (t){};

%%% blues edges
\draw[thick, blue] (z) to[bend right=25] node[pointred, midway] (zx){} (x)
    (z) to[bend left=45]node[pointred, midway] (z1x1){} (x)
    (x) to node[pointred, midway](x1t1){} (t)
    (x) to[bend left=60] node[pointred, midway] (x2t2){} (t)
    (x) to[bend right=60] node[pointred, midway] (xt){} (t);

% reds edges
\draw[thick, red] (x2t2) to[bend right = 60] (z1x1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```